# Adding values in scripted field in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am writing Scripted Fields in Kibana. I am able to run simple query successfully but I need to add two different fields in single scripted field.

The query looks as follows:

```
if((doc['some_field'].value=some value) && (doc['some_field2'].value=some value2))
{
return "some text"
}
else if((doc['some_field'].value=some value3) && (doc['some_field2'].value=some value4))
{
return "some text2"
}
```

Now I want to sum up result of both in third loop.I have written as

```
if((doc['some_field'].value=some value) && (doc['some_field2'].value=some value2))
    {
    return "some text"
    }
    else if((doc['some_field'].value=some value3) && (doc['some_field2'].value=some value4))
    {
    return "some text2"
    }
else if((doc['some_field'].value=some value) && (doc['some_field2'].value=some value2)) || 
((doc['some_field'].value=some value3) && (doc['some_field2'].value=some value4)))
    {
    return "some text3"
    }
```

But its not showing third value.

If anyone having any idea on how to do it please share your knowledge.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: This cannot work since in the third condition you have the first and second conditions ORed. So if either the first or the second matches, you'll never make it to the third condition. You need to bring the third condition to the first position and test it first. Logic 101 :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Yes.I have tried these also but then second and third condition was not working.So,Do you know any alternative to achieve these.

Comment: Why can't the final statement be it's own independent IF statement (not an else if)?

Comment: Tried with that but still it's not working.Means executed only two conditions not last one.